# Does VMware mask system specs?

Tags: vmware

From my understanding sites can fingerprint you on your system specs, such as your local computer hardware specification and resolution.

Does VMware mask this data?

Answer (score 2):

Virtual machines in VMware emulate most devices, so those will not be tied to your host hardware.  The main exception is your CPU, which is visible to the guest.  USB devices that you have configured to connect to the VM also will be visible to the guest.

And, of course, if you run the VM in full screen mode and enable automatically changing the resolution, the VM obviously can use the same resolution as your host.